# Back Button is not working when alertbox is present

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I implemented **Alert Box** in my application.When alertbox is pops up in that state **BACK** button is not working in application.Please help me how to over write this.

CODE::

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder2.setTitle("EXIT");

    alertDialogBuilder2.setMessage("ARE YOU SURE?").setCancelable(false)

    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TAKE CARE and BYE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
      })
    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });


    AlertDialog alertDialog2 = alertDialogBuilder2.create();
    alertDialog2.show();
```

Comment: cancelable isn't set to true so you cannot cancel your dialog. Just set .setCancelable(true)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Set

```
alertDialogBuilder2.setCancelable(true);
```

Another Solution:

```
  alertDialogBuilder2.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){

                dialog.dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

**You should change your method dialog.cancel() to dialog.dimiss()**

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
     alertDialogBuilder2.setTitle("EXIT");

     alertDialogBuilder2.setMessage("ARE YOU SURE?").setCancelable(false)

    .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TAKE CARE and BYE",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
      })
    .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });


    AlertDialog alertDialog2 = alertDialogBuilder2.create();
    alertDialog2.show();
```